# Fastest way to add a video event in multiple cuts

Tags: vegas-pro

I made a lot of cuts from many videos. Now, what if I want to add a video event in multiple pieces?

I could click, in every piece of video, the video event button to add one, and do the same thing over and over again... but that would consume tons of time and will. And if I highlight multiple ones and right click in one of them, the option goes grey.

Is there any trick to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If by Video Event, you mean Video Event FX, then apply the effect to one event. Right-click and select `Copy`. Then select the remaining clips, right-click and select `Paste Event Attributes`. Note that all the original Pan/Crop and effects applied to the other clips will be overwritten with those in the copied clip.